# Easy way of creating executable JavaFX?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, javafx-2, executable

Is there an easy, one-click way of creating an executable JavaFX file?

I have an JavaFX application functioning when I run it in Netbeans. Is there a way I could get a single file on my desktop that would run the application without the need of Netbeans?

I've read a lot of different tutorials, but I'm not looking for a tutorial. Way too much work for one single file. And a tutorial should not be needed for this. It should be as easy as clicking a button *Frustrated*.

Plugins for Netbeans are ok. Is there any way of doing this?
I don't care what type of file it is, as long as it can run independent of Netbeans, and that it can be run without a command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want but you can give it a try.

Select your project and (clean &) build it. Then click the Files tab , select your project and check under the `dist` folder. There you will find, among others, a `.jar` file. click the file and your application will run.

I am using NetBeans 8.0 and have loaded one of the samples for JavaFX:DigitalClock

Comment: Doesn't work for me. A command prompt shows, then goes away, but no application window. I guess I'll troubleshoot it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Nvm. Worked with an added batch file that has this line in it: "java -jar jarFileName.jar". Thanks.

Comment: try also to right click your project and select properties, then check `build` and `run` options

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans and other IDEs have support for the javafxpackager. I'm not useing netbeans but eclipse which makes the feature available as shown in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1 but i'm sure Netbeans provides something similar!

If you target JDK8 only the other answer is correct but i'd still suggest to use javafxpackager to eg create a setup.exe which eg includes a jre so people don't have to have java installed on the system

Answer (score 0):

You can use Launch4j. Its very simple to use

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/